# How can I automate hosting Angular app on IIS server using Jenkins Pipeline?

Tags: angular, jenkins, iis, jenkins-pipeline

Deploy angular application in a virtual machine and deploy it to IIS with help of Jenkins pipeline

I have successfully build and deploy it in VM but hosting in IIS server I need to do it through Jenkins basically want automate the hosting in IIS server part also so how can I do it any idea what I need to add in batch command or Jenkins file

Answer (score 2):

Set up your Jenkins pipeline:

1. Open Jenkins and create a new pipeline job.
   Configure the necessary settings such as the repository URL and credentials.
   In the pipeline configuration, select the "Pipeline script" option.
2. Write the Jenkins pipeline script: In the Jenkins pipeline script,
   you'll need to define the stages of your deployment process.

```
pipeline {
  agent any

  stages {
    stage('Build') {
      steps {
        // Add the commands to build your Angular application
        sh 'npm install'
        sh 'ng build --prod'
      }
    }

    stage('Deploy to IIS') {
      steps {
        // Add the commands to deploy the build artifacts to IIS
        bat 'xcopy /s /y "dist\\*" "C:\\inetpub\\wwwroot"'
      }
    }

    stage('Create IIS Application') {
      steps {
        script {
          // Get the branch name from the environment variable
          def branchName = env.BRANCH_NAME

          // Generate the application name based on the branch name
          def appName = branchName.replaceAll("/", "-").toLowerCase()

          // Set the IIS application path
          def appPath = "Default Web Site/${appName}"

          // Set the application pool name
          def appPoolName = "MyAppPool"

          // Create the IIS application
          bat "appcmd add app /site.name:\"Default Web Site\" /path:\"/${appName}\" /physicalPath:\"C:\\inetpub\\wwwroot\\${appName}\""

          // Set the application pool for the newly created application
          bat "appcmd set app /app.name:\"Default Web Site/${appName}\" /applicationPool:\"${appPoolName}\""
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

You can edit build stage to not only instal node_module via npm install and build via ng build --prod. But add some other custom configuration or commands like run test or even add new stage for tests etc...

Adjust the path in the xcopy command in the Deploy to IIS stage if your IIS server's webroot is located in a different directory.

Save the pipeline script in your Jenkins job configuration.
Run the Jenkins job, and it will execute the defined stages to build your Angular application and deploy it to the IIS server.

Mostly I have one of the jenkins file in Angular project. So if I made some of the commit to master/dev branche it will automaticaly run that pipeline job from jenskinsfile.

Comment: Yes it worked but also want to automate the create apppool and defaultwebsite this steps from jenkins

Comment: Is there a way to make my build script automatically create "IIS applications" and set the application pool for any newly discovered branches

Comment: @SubharoopGhosh I eddited answer. I hope this helps you. I have added comments as well. Feel free to ask if you have any questions.

Comment: How to add more than one environment variables to specific app pool from pipeline? Could you show an example?